# Save a file to a GDB

Tags: python, gis, arcpy, arcmap

I'm writing a script to subtract one raster from another (Minus) and save the result in a geodatabase. The script works if I save the result to a normal folder:

```
arcpy.gp.Minus_sa("204nw06_c_r.tif","204nw06_be_r.tif","S:/Working_Folder/204nw06")
```

It fails when I try to save it to the gdb. It works in ArcCatalog and this is the Python snippet it gave me:

```
arcpy.gp.Minus_sa("214ne02_c_r.tif","214ne02_be_r.tif","S:/Working_Folder/LiDarTest.gdb/214ne02")
```

Can I save the result directly to the GDB? Or do I move the files to the GDB in a separate step?

Comment: What is your error message?

Answer (score 3):

You may try:

```
arcpy.gp.Minus_sa("214ne02_c_r.tif","214ne02_be_r.tif","S:/Working_Folder/LiDarTest.gdb/A214ne02")
```

In GDB, a raster name can't begin with number.